# Why is $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{iz}}{e^{iz}}dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I have come across this line
$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{iz}}{e^{iz}}dz = 2\pi i$$
and I don't understand it. How does it change from being $\frac{1}{z}$ to $ie^{iz}/e^{iz}$? I would have like to write it in polar form as something like $\frac{1}{e^{it}}$, but then the integral would be equal to $0$...

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Example

Comment: You can follow this:$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}}dt = 2\pi i$. The $t$ in the middle here is a dummy variable. It is written $z$ in your original equations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply the defnition of [complex line integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral).

The (closed, clock-wise) curve $C = \{|z| = 1\}$ can be parametrized via the function $g(z) = e^{iz}$ for $z \in [0, 2\pi]$. Observe that $g'(z) = i e^{iz}$. Now this means that for a function $f$ that is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $C$ we have
$$\oint_C f(z) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} i e^{it} f(e^{it}) \, dt$$

Specifically, $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ yields
$$\oint_C \frac{1}{z} \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} i e^{it} \frac{1}{e^{it}} \, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} i \, dt = 2\pi i.$$

Answer (score 2):

You are right and wrong:

$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it}}{e^{it}}dt =\int_0^{2\pi} i dt= 2\pi i$

Comment: Ah, well that is at least a little bit less confusing (the z-part in $e^{iz}$ was freaking me out a little), however, I still don't quite understand that first equality.

Comment: @Fred Did you forget to insert an $=$ sign between the two integrals which now appear to be multiplied?

Comment: OOOPs ! You are right ! An edit will follow.

Comment: ?? I  can't see an extra integral sign ?

Comment: There were two when I wrote the above comment (when at that time the middle equal sign was missing, which is now fixed-- hard to keep track of exactly what time things change at this site, and likely not all readers get the latest changes at the same instant.